# Are types in Coq mutually exclusive?

Tags: coq

**Question:**

Are types in Coq mutually exclusive?

For example in the accepted answer for this question:
[What exactly is a Set in COQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601502/what-exactly-is-a-set-in-coq)

it is mentioned that "Set <= Type_0". (Does it mean that anything of type Set is also of type Type?)

On the other hand in the accepted answer for this question:
[Making and comparing Sets in Coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30021337/making-and-comparing-sets-in-coq)

it is mentioned that "each valid element of the language has exactly one type".

**My motivation:**

Relations in Coq (in Relations: [Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.html)) are defined as:

```
Variable A : Type.
Definition relation := A -> A -> Prop.
```

My intention was to express a restriction of a relation to some "smaller" B. If the types are mutually exclusive then it may make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sense asked, yes, types are exclusive.

You cannot express a restriction to some smaller `B`, at least not between sorts like `Set/Prop/Type(0)` - everything contained in one sort is also contained in larger sorts.

Subtyping in Coq is a little different from traditional languages. `Set <= Type(0)` means anything of type `Set` can be promoted to having type `Type(0)`, not that it always has `Type(0)`. Subtyping between sorts is explained in CIC/Sorts section of the [Coq Manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/language/cic.html#sorts).

However, if you are using Type Classes, you can define restriction of relations on subclasses! For example, you can define a type class which has the "+" operator and define a subclass where the "+" operator is associative.